# vba script for accesing webpage from a frame

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to download the data from a site using VBA script excel macro [link](https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/ipos/ipo_current_quess.htm) , but the data i am interested in resides within a webpage frame , the url of the main page and the frame is not getting change.

[image: The frame i am interested in has been pointed in the pic]

Following is the macro which is working fine for the main page , please help me out in downloading the same from within a web frame.

```
 'Microsoft HTML Office Library
Sub webtable_NSE()
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim objElementsTd As Object
    Dim objTd As Object
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim myarray()
    Dim oIE As InternetExplorer
    Set oIE = New InternetExplorer
    oIE.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/ipos/ipo_current_quess.htm"

    'javascript:loadIpoBidDetails('/products/content/equities/ipos/Quess_curr_ipo_bid_details.htm')
    'oIE.Navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/ipos/Quess_curr_ipo_bid_details.htm"

    Do Until (oIE.readyState = 4 And Not oIE.Busy)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = oIE.Document.body.innerHTML
    With HTMLDoc.body
        Set elemcollection = .getElementsByTagName("Table")
        For t = 0 To elemcollection.Length - 1
            For r = 0 To elemcollection(t).Rows.Length - 1
                For c = 0 To elemcollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NSE").Cells(ActRw + r + 1, c + 1) = elemcollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                Next c
            Next r
            ActRw = ActRw + elemcollection(t).Rows.Length + 1
        Next t
    End With
    oIE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/ipos/QUESS_curr_ipo_bid_details.htm

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do what you want without VBA.

In the Data tab, you can click From Web, Adress: https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/ipos/QUESS_curr_ipo_bid_details.htm and click Import. After that, You can change the connection properties to "Refresh data when opening the file" or control when the data is refreshed with VBA

Answer (score 1):

If you know the URL containing the table data you want, you don't have to try and automate IE to 'get there' - you can just send a HTTP request against that particular URL. The library you are looking for is MSXML2 XMLHTTP - here's a code sample returning your data:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetTableData()

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim strHtml As String
    Dim blnAsync As Boolean

    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/ipos/QUESS_curr_ipo_bid_details.htm"
    blnAsync = True

    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
        .Send
        While .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        strHtml = .responseText
    End With

    Debug.Print strHtml

End Sub
```